# Need help identifying an Apple IIc game/possibly educational with a top-down view

Tags: apple-ii, identify-this-game

Played it around the end of the 80's but most probably developed between 1981 and 1986.
You had control over a person/avatar (not stick figure like, more plump looking) and could walk from scene to scene; these locations (museum, plaza maybe) or rooms contained scattered items like masks, horns, pots, etc. and some wandering people (including a policeman in some places).
It had a memorable tune but nothing I can compare it to.
Possible use of Egyptian and/or British themes.
A decades old mystery of mine, been searching from time to time and I'm starting to believe it was a figment of my young imagination.

Comment: It's probably not this, but see if [Copts and Robbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxvLabXNnlI) jogs your memory.

Comment: The avatar and NPCs were more human like.
Another thing I remember: Item placement inside the locations was very similar to the one used in the rooms of Dragonfire (http://www.intvfunhouse.com/imagic/games/fire-02.png)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I *was* going to say potentially one of these ...

- [The Heist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZpcoaYib_Y)
- [Spare Change](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBuJK4geIiw)

but then you said "top-down view" so that rules out "sidescrollers"

Next task is to go through Wikipedia's list of [Apple 2 Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apple_II_games) ...

I'm wondering if it was an action RPG along the lines of:

- [Gemstone Warrior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7cxjYqVF8I)
- [Lady Tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOUgZpf4a_A)

Any chance you remember any more details, such as the what size was the avatar? Or specific colors?

Comment: Checked the four suggestions but no luck. The wiki list was used to determine the year range of the game considering the other games I played during the same time, Lady Tut was one of them.
The size was relatively small considering that each scene used a fixed layout, not scrolling as in Gemstone Warrior, and also contained the "NPCs" plus 5 to 10 artifacts.
Cannot recall specific coloring other than white outlines for the avatars over completely black floors.